# High Memory usage by Java (TM) Platform SE binary

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

We are noticing that IBM MobileFirst Server is using High Memory by Java TM Platform SE binary process, after 2 3 days of server start it reach up to 6 GB which cause the server in hang status,  then only restart is the solution.
in logs we found below message:
"No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect"

Enviornment: IBm Worklight Server 7.1 and java version is 1.7 64 bit on windows server 2012. hybrid Mobile application running on this server.

It seems that there might be some configuration required can any one advice ?

Comment: Lots of information missing: are you in a cluster? if yes, how many servers? how many adapters? What is the value you gave to the  `serverSessionTimeout` property? all of these and more can contribute to how much memory you may need.

Comment: FYI, this question is not suitable to StackOverflow; consider removing it and opening an IBM PMR instead.

Answer (score -1):

Lots of information missing... this can be caused by any number of reasons.

- Are you in a cluster? if yes, how many servers? how much memory is available to each machine?
- How many adapters do you have deployed? What is the value you gave to the `serverSessionTimeout` property? This for example can cause connections to stay open for a longer time, meaning the server will not "clean/remove" connections... and the more you have open, the more memory you will require.

all of these and more can contribute to how much memory you may need.

See also: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21690707
It mentions DB2, but the idea is - the more connections, the more memory you will need.

Comment: Thanks Idan, we are in cluster with 2 server and it is happening on one of the server , we have around 100 adapters but did not find serverSessionTimeout value can you please advice where can we set this value

Comment: It is in the worklight.properties file of your MobileFirst project (project\server folder).